# Error in Json Serialization "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, serialization, datareader

Json serialization command is giving this error. I used `Newtonsoft.Json` to avoid the cyclic reference error on serialization.

```
private IQueryable<Study> GetStudiesData()
{
    var currUser = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
    var currUserRole = currUser.Roles.First();

    IQueryable<Study> studies;
    if (User.IsInRole("SuperAdmin")) {
        studies = db.Studies; //all studies from all centers 
    }
    else {
        var assignedStudies = db.Studies.Where(s => s.AssignedUserID == currUser.Id);

        studies = db.Studies.Where(s => s.User.CenterId == currUser.CenterId && s.RoleID == currUserRole.RoleId)
            .Concat(assignedStudies);
    }

    return studies;
}

//ajax call to this function gives error
public ActionResult GetStudies(int pageSize = 10, int pageNum = 1)
{
    var studies = GetStudiesData();
    var studiesCount = studies.Count();
    var studiesPaged = studies.OrderBy(s=>s.PatientID).Skip(pageSize*pageNum).Take(pageSize);

    var result = new { TotalRows = studiesCount, Rows = studiesPaged };

    //this line gives error
    //There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.
    var data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None,
    new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
    });

    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I tried `result = studies`, `result = studiesPaged`, `result = studiesCount` in `var data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, ...)`.
Only `studiesPaged` is giving the error.

I can solve it using `MultipleActiveResultSets=True;` but where am I doing the second query?

### Update

public ActionResult GetStudies(int pageSize = 10, int pageNum = 1)
{
    var studies = GetStudiesData().ToList(); //solved, created another issue
    //other code
}

Now the Json returned looks like a Json is again serialized to string.

```
"{\"TotalRows\":5,\"Rows\":[{\"AssignedUser\":null, ..... }]}"
```

When parsed by javascript it is all splitted to an array of characters.

### Update2

Changed

```
//data is a json string after serialization
return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); //Serializing the Json
```

to

```
return Content(data, "application/json");
```

Comment: Have you tried assigning it to a list, this should force the close of the connection.

Comment: @nik0lias Assigning solves the issue but json returned looks like serialized two times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assigning it to a list, and then querying it should prevent this:

```
public ActionResult GetStudies(int pageSize = 10, int pageNum = 1)
{
    var studies = GetStudiesData().ToList();
    var studiesCount = studies.Count();
    var studiesPaged = studies.OrderBy(s=>s.PatientID).Skip(pageSize*pageNum).Take(pageSize);

    var result = new { TotalRows = studiesCount, Rows = studiesPaged };

    //this line gives error
    //There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.
    var data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None,
    new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
    });

    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: The json received is read as all single characters. If I open the json separately in a tab it reads fine. What is wrong with that json?

Comment: Because the ToList() assigns it to a new collection and forces the close of the DataReader.

Comment: Are you calling this via Ajax or something similar? When you say a new tab, is this opened by yourself and then the URL typed manually?

Comment: I am calling it with Ajax, I used new tab to see what's wrong with returned json

Comment: I can only assume that the parameters being passed to the Ajax call are affecting the results?

Comment: json return is like this `"{\"TotalRows\":5}"`

Comment: If you step through it, is there anything in the studiesPaged object.  What is in the data object before it is returned in a Json result? Please update your question.

Comment: `return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` found the culprit. Serializing the Json itself. meh

Answer (score 1):

```
var assignedStudies = db.Studies.Where(s => s.AssignedUserID == currUser.Id);

studies = db.Studies.Where(s => s.User.CenterId == currUser.CenterId && 
              s.RoleID == currUserRole.RoleId).Concat(assignedStudies);
```

You have two queries to `DbSet<Studies>` here

Comment: But it works without any problem if I don't do paging `Take` and `Skip`

Comment: Tried different values of pagenum*pagesize . Any value which results in no data runs fine and returns empty json

Comment: replaced with single query but the error persists `studies = db.Studies.Where(s => (s.User.CenterId == currUser.CenterId && s.RoleID == currUserRole.RoleId) || s.AssignedUserID == currUser.Id);`